# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am getting this strange crash reports on Lollipop. My app is basically a browser so it makes heavy use of the WebView but I don't know that the issue is happening there. Anyways the crash report doesn't give much useful information, it is essentially what I am pasting below:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nDeleteProxy(Native Method)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize(ThreadedRenderer.java:398)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Has anyone seen this? any idea what might be causing it?

EDIT: I should mention that this is happening on an app which I've had for about 10 months and it has always only targeted 4.0+ devices. The bug is only being reported on 5.0 devices and that stacktrace above is all the Play Store Console gives me.

Comment: Is `android:hardwareAccelerated` set to `true` ?

Comment: Yes although I'm probably going to change it to false in the near future because of a different bug with WebView.

Comment: Most likely, you are tripping over a bug in Android 5.0 itself. Reading the source code, it seems unlikely that there is something that you are doing that would cause the native `nDeleteProxy()` method to hang. If you wind up being able to reproduce the bug at some point, upload a test project as part of an issue to http://b.android.com.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was starting to think the same thing but I just have not been able to reproduce. I think my two 5.0 bugs I have are mostly happening on Nexus 5 devices which is the one Nexus device I don't have for testing.

Comment: Any luck removing hardware acceleration ?

Comment: I have removed it and haven't had a crash report yet for this issue but I am doing a staged release so maybe not enough people have it or my lollipop users gave up :(

Comment: I am getting a similar issue for lollipop users. Did disabling hardware acceleration solve the issue ?

Comment: I have same error but I don't use `WebView`

Answer (score 12):

Since KitKat, I have issues with `WebViews` (freeze, crash)

I have resolved these issues deactivating hardware acceleration for `webViews`. It could work for you.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) // KITKAT
{
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Comment: use Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT instead of 19 value

Comment: @ToYonos is this still the preferred workaround? Also, I think that this Chromium issue (unresolved) is related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=448389

Comment: I use webView for playing stream video. As soon as I set this feature my player is became dark entirely.