# Again ERROR java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

**Please don't mark as duplicate**

I get this error very often on crashlytics, and I can't find the problem. I saw it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232275/java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-view-threadedrenderer-finalize) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021609/how-to-handle-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-os-binderproxy-fin) but  I don't have any WebViews in my app.

I have in my app some AsyncTasks that are processing some date: select from DB, compare and call the listener to update UI when is done (I check if activity is still visible when it's needed to update UI). This processing can be long if user has 10k records to compare.

Have to mention that error happens for different devices manufacturers (more on Samsung) and on different Android versions (more on Andorid 6.0 +)

I get this error many times as different one, for example:

> File: Daemons.java:217

```
 java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
1   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nDeleteProxy(Native Method)
2   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize(ThreadedRenderer.java:459)
3   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:217)
4   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:200)
5   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

> File: Daemons.java:206

```
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
1   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nDeleteProxy(Native Method)
2   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize(ThreadedRenderer.java:449)
3   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:206)
4   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:189)
5   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

> File Daemons.java:210

```
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 15 seconds
1   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nDeleteProxy(Native Method)
2   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize(ThreadedRenderer.java:427)
3   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:210)
4   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:193)
5   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

etc...

Comment: Are you using a TextureView or SurfaceView?

Comment: @Choletski, Just wondering if found any solution on this? Are you still seeing this issue? I have been seeing this crash, in the Dynatrace for my app.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the posts you link to describes, this is an exception being generated by garbage collection taking too long for an object with a native code implementation.  I ran into this exception and found a solution by looking at the source code producing this exception `java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.finalizerTimedOut()` which you can see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a7752f4d22097346dd7849b92b9f36d0a0a7a8f3/libdvm/src/main/java/java/lang/Daemons.java).

In `finalizerTimedOut()`, if `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() == null`, it create and logs a `TimeoutException()` and exits with a non-zero code `(System.exit(2);)`!  To the user, this will look like an FC!  To prevent this, you need to call `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to catch and handle this exception.